# pass a list as a parameter to django tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a custom inclusion tag in Django, and I need to pass there a list as a parameter. Something along these lines:

```
 {% my_tag paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' listparams=['X', 'Y'] %}
```

This of course does not work because Django does not know how to deal with lists passed that way.

I can also capture something general like `list_` and then combine them into a list on a server side:

```
 {% my_tag paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' list_1='X' list_2='Y' list_3='Z' %}
```

But I wonder if there is a nicer way of dealing with this.

Comment: Can't you use the `*args` for this? So positional parameters in the head? It would probably be helpful to give more details about `my_tag`.

Comment: Posting as answer as I am new here and don't have enough reputation to post as comment. But this is just a addendum to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52091656/3036846) above. Split() on string literal didn't work for me, got parsing error, but capturing string in a variable and then using split() worked {% with listparams_literal='XY Z' %} {% my_tag paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' listparams=listparams_literal.split %}

Answer (score 8):

There are basically two approaches here:

1. trying to *construct* a list, one way or another, and pass it to `my_tag`; or
2. change `my_tag` such that passing a list is more convenient.

## Constructing lists

Django templates offer ways to construct a list, although most of these are rather limited.

### Using the `make_list` template filter

Django for example introduces a [**`make_list`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) that takes an iterable, and converts it to a list of the items. For example we can use the template filter with:

```
{% my_tag paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' listparams='XY'|make_list %}
```

But there are two potential problems with this: (1) for a string it iterates over the characters, so the elements will all be 1-character strings, and (2) you can not construct lists that contain integers, etc. unless you already have a collection-like object, but this would basically make the `make_list` useless.

### Using `.split()`

We can solve the problem that it only takes 1-character strings, by performing a call to `.split()`, this works only for strings (unless the type of the variable also supports a `.split()` function), so we can solve the problem with mulit-char parts with:

```
{% my_tag paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' listparams='XY Z'.split %}
```

### Implement a custom variadic tag to construct lists

We can also define a variadic tag, that first construct a list. We do this by implementing a custom tag:

```
#  app/templatetags/create_list.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def create_list(*args):
    return args
```

We can then use two steps to pass a list:

```
{% load create_list %}
{% create_list 'X' 'Y' as mylist %}
{% my_tag paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' listparams=mylist %}
```

## Changing `my_tag`

Perhaps a clean way could be to make use of *positional* parameters here to obtain the list. A function in Python has two types of parameters: *positional* ones (the ones passed *without* the name of the parameter), and *named* ones (the ones with `key=...`).

We can thus use the positional ones here for the list, and thus call the tag with:

```
{% my_tag 'X' 'Y' paramA='asdf' paramB='fdsa' %}
```

In case we do not mention any positional parameters, the list is thus considered empty. We can pass an arbitrary number of parameters.

We can for example implement the tag as:

```
#  app/templatetags/my_tag.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def my_tag(*listparams, paramA=None, paramB=None):
    # ... processing
    return None
```

A potential problem with this approach is that we can only perform this "trick" once, in the sense that we can not define two separate such `*arg`s. We can of course aim to split the `*args` into two lists, but this can be tricky.